How To Redirect In Post Request Response
i wanna redirect to success page but it seems i should use different way in post request response.
views.py :
def uploader(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect("download",link = 'test')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'uploader/pages/upload.html', {'form': form})

def downloader(request,link) :
    return render(request, 'uploader/pages/download.html',)

urls.py :
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', views.uploader, name='upload'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<link>[\w-]+)/', views.downloader, name='download'),
]

log in terminal :
[27/Jul/2024 17:43:37] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[27/Jul/2024 17:43:37] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46

I've tried HttpResponseRedirect('test') and HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('download', kwargs={'link': 'link'})) to

It makes the redirect: it redirects indeed to /test/, so it makes a GET request...

@willeM_ Van Onsem .But it doesn't change the page or url

do you load this through an AJAX call?

@willeM_ Van Onsem .no i used fetch

well that is also AJAX iirc? Just like axios, these do the redirect, but not as "window" screen, you could say the redirect happens in the "fetch environment".

After correct questions in comments I understand.
You use fetch on client-side to made request to back-end per javascript. It is not Django resposibility, but I try to answer.
After fetch request on client-side, you should initiate a programmatic redirect on client-side if you receive a redirect response.
window.location.repelace(response.headers.get('location')) 

But if we read documentation about fetch - we can see, we can do redirect automatically, add in fetch additional attribute:
fetch (url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'follow'}) 

more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestInit#redirect
